# Voltage Controlled Oscillators

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, analog, design, oscillator

I want to know how to calculate the gain of a VCO.  I've looked online and see that there exists a formula

$$K_{VCO} = \dfrac{f_1-f_2}{V_1-V_2}$$

but it would seem that this result would give outrageously high gain values.  For examples, for a VCO operating the MHz region, would it be realistic to see that the VCO gain value be in the range of millions as well? (This assuming that I would believe the control voltage value is in the range of 1-10 volts.

Is there another way I can calculate this value?  It just seems unreasonable to me to get such a huge gain factor.

EDIT/ADD-ON:  As an add-on example, assume I had some data for a VCO, and I used a "curve/equation fit" and the resulting equation is of the form y = mx+b. Is Kvco is this case still equal to 'm'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you pasted is correct and makes perfect sense. It's purely descriptive. This gain formula is a simple way of describing the VCO by its voltage input and frequency ranges.

A VCO operating within the MHz range, powered by 10V will have a huge gain. For every volt on its input, the output will rise by millions of Hertz. Unless you of course design a high frequency VCO with a very fine-tuned output (e.g. from 100MHz to 100.01MHz).

Comment: fair enough.  I suppose as an add-on, what if there is an offset?  I have yet to come across a formula that deals with this.  For example, assume I had some data for a VCO, and I used a "curve/equation fit" and the resulting equation is of the form y = mx+b.  Is Kvco is this case still equal to 'm'?  
Thanks.
(Perhaps I should add this to my main post as well.)

Comment: To fully describe a circuit that incorporates a VCO, a characteristic voltage/frequency curve is used. The Kvco is only a linear approximation of the curve to make simulation easier. From the non-linear experimentally derived curve all parameters are obtained. Min and max frequencies, the free-running frequency(or offset), the slope (or Kvco).

Answer (score 1):

The formula is correct. Regarding expected gain, that highly depends on the oscillator topology. For example [ring oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_oscillator) tends to have much bigger gain the LC tank based oscillators. I have seen ring and LC VCOs working at similar frequency and ring oscillator had GHz/V gain while LC had tens of MHz/V gain.